# Uncompress gzcompress string in JavaScript (jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, compression

I have a html5 based mobile application, where I send data from the server (PHP) in textual format.

The problem is that my Data is pretty big, around ***18Mo*** but when compressed using [`gzcompress`](http://php.net/gzcompress) it became a lot smaller.

**My Problem is how uncompress the string back in JavaScript** I used the plugin [JXG](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/)  and its working very well in both browser and simulator but the app crashes when running in my iPad 2, does any one know a better way ?

Comment: My guess would be that it crashes because the uncompressing takes a long time, your page stops responding and the iPad kills your app because it is not responding. You might be able to solve this by doing the unzipping in the backgoround using a web worker, though Android does not seem to support web workers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out, can you please give me link or something as I never heard before about **web worker** ?

Comment: this is a good explanation: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/ it's a really cool technology actually. you will want to write your code so that id uses web workers if they are available to the browser but works anyway if they are not, as web worker support is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

A few month ago, I made a function which uncompress gzip files... [Try it](https://github.com/gcanu/gzip.js)... Hope this help you. If you have some question, mail me !

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I'm getting a bit trouble using it, can you give me a hint ?

Comment: :-) this project is not finished !!! So, it's require a "little" work to use this lib !!! Add gzip.js to your lib folder... To decompress, put your compressed bytes into string and execute decompress function with the string as parameter... The uncompressed string will be returned !

Comment: I tried this, but I got an error saying, `decompress` function is not defined

Comment: I've made an update... Download the new version or update your repo